# Is there an option to run second time the same program in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm creating simple online game in Qt Creator. I've created server project which analyse received data and take decisions. Also I created player project which sends requests to server for permission to move, shoot etc. Player project should be universal for Player 1 and Player 2.

Is there an option to run player project twice in Qt Creator?
I need it to test how server and player project behaves when second player connects.

Comment: Have you tried to run the executable from outside QtCreator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open 3 Qt Creators, 1 for the server 2 for the players and then run all of them. I have made a server-client multiplayer game in Qt and that is how i tested it.
For every client(player) open a Qt Creator.

EDIT: 
You can also create release versions and start them, but you waste a lot of time creating a release version every time you want to debug.

Comment: I thought there could be one Qt Creator opened at time. Thanks, it works, with one problem. In second Qt Creator i have message something like: "cannot download debugger communicates". I need these communicates, is there any way to have communicates from qDebug on both Qt Creators?

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't think of any other way of launching your application than starting multiple instances of your IDE? - *really*?  Did you consider just starting the app multiple times from a shell? Or you could edit your "run" configuration in creator to start the app multiple times.. There are so many better ways.. This solution is just .. I don't know what to say .. A hack (at best)...

Comment: For the qDebug problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379325/cannot-retrieve-debugging-output-in-qt-creator

Comment: @JesperJuhl I editied and added another way. I didn't say it is a great solution but it is better then having none ;/  i was just trying to help the best i can

Comment: I wanted quick solution, and i got it. I believe there are more sophisticated solutions, but that one solves my problem aswell.

Comment: @Milos Radosavljevic How does "creating a release version" have anything to do with it? Regardless of you doing a "release" or "debug" build, an executable is generated by the compiler that you can just run (as many times as you care to) in a shell (or by clicking in your GUI if you like). Release vs Debug changes nothing. Starting multiple IDE instances is just a crappy solution.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Qt Creator 4.3.1: You can do that in **Tools** > **Options...** > **Build & Run**. Under the **General** tab, set the "**Stop applications before building:**" to "**None**"